# What does a non-booting macbook displaying a lightning bolt mean?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, startup

I returned to my MacBook after a few days of not using it, and there was a message that the system had run out of application memory (weird...). So, I followed the recommendation and Force Quit a bunch of applications. In order to just "start fresh", I decided to kill all applications and simply restart the whole machine.

Now that I've killed the applications and restarted the computer, it won't boot. It simply displays a gray circle with a white lightning bolt on it, moving around the screen, screensaver-style. If I unplug the AC power cord, a battery indicator is displayed at the bottom of the screen.

I attempted an SMC reset, but that doesn't help. What's going on, and what should I do?

[image]

Comment: That was it!  My keyboard is broken (it usually continually types the letter "T", so I have to disable it and use an external keyboard).  So, when I rebooted, the system interpreted the keyboard's input as "use Target Disk Mode".  I simply held down the "Cmd" key so that it became "Cmd-T", which prevented TDM.  I've successfully booted!

Comment: If you add an answer in this regard, I'll accept it.  Good to have this knowledge stick around in the rare case someone else has the problem! :)

Comment: Good to hear that your Mac works! I'll add my comment as an answer, then.

Comment: Me ttttoo.  Thanks!ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

Comment: Seriously, me oo! https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297518/delays-or-skipping-for-single-key-on-keyboard Did you need a hardware fix in he end?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That looks like the Thunderbolt logo. Your Mac probably thinks that is in Target Disk Mode.

Comment: It *was* TDM!  See my comment on the original question for what I did to "fix" the problem.

Comment: Wow ... have the same problem with the same letter t busted on the built in keyboard. Is it worth replacing the keyboard?

Comment: I have the same problem (non-working/repeating "t"). Apple (Genius Bar) said it would cost $475 to replace the keyboard, because they have to replace the screen at the same time. Still a lot cheaper than a new Macbook Pro, so I'm going to do this.

Answer (score 2):

NVRAM holds the info on where/how to boot (Target Disk Mode). You need to reset the [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

Answer (score 0):

Watch on the right of your mac, on top it has the same symbol as the logo you are showing. It is probably a cable that needs to be plugged in. If you think this means trouble go to your local apple store.