# Delays or skipping for single key on keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

The 'T' key on my 2014 macbook pro is behaving strangely.

It sometimes works, but often doesn't. Mostly it skips completely. Other times it has a delay, such that I type the words correctly, but the T appears out of sequence.  Once in a while it will work great for a minute or less.

I don't suspect a dirty key because sometimes he 'T' will appear after I have released the key. I have cleaned under the key anyway and it looks good. I have reset NVRAM and SMC.

To illustrate the problem, here's this question as it was originally typed, before I painstakingly fixed it up.

```
he 'T' key on my 2014 macbook pro is behaving srangely.

I someimes works, bu ofetn doesn'. Mosly i skips compleetly. Oher imes i has a delay, such ha I ype he words correcly, bu hte T appears ou of sequence. Once in a while i will work grea for a minue or less.

I don' suspec ta diry key because someimes he 'T' will appear afer I have released he key. I have cleaned under he key anyway and i looks good. I have rese NVRAM and SMC.
```

Can I fix it?

**Edit - answering questions in the comments:**

Testing behaviour a bit more, I realise that many of my apps don't permit repeating (including chrome and IDEA). So I've tested in vi where repeating works. The key's behaviour seems more consistent:

- There is a delay of around 1 second before the 't' character appears and another delay of about 1 second before the repeating stops after key release. The keypress signal is delayed 1 second.
- It seems unaffected by temperature.
- As of this afternoon, the delete key is also affected.

Comment: What happens if you hold the key? Is the repeat rate always stuttering or smooth and according to settings, once it gets going?  Also, please keep a watch on the temperatures: more skipping with higher temps? Reduced skipping with forced cooling? Sometimes other keys affected? Same row?

Comment: @LangLangC please see updated question

Comment: As of this afternoon, the delete key is also affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a defective keyboard. Yah it's difficult, nigh impossible, to diagnose hardware via messages on the internet but that is my guess.

It may be possible to find a used, working, keyboard on eBay or the like, if you feel up to replacing it yourself. iFixIt likely has a take apart guide that would show you how difficult it would be to do it.

If you are anywhere near an Apple Store I would make a full backup of your system. Create a new admin user for Apple to use and take it in to an Apple Store for diagnosis and/or repair.

Comment: I went to Apple. It was out of warranty, but they fixed it anyway. What I learnt along the way is that you should not allow macbooks to get hot for a sustained period of time and definitely not in clamshell mode. The heat will destroy the top case.

Comment: Do you know how they fixed it? Replaced the entire keyboard? Or something else?